# Unchanged service worker is re-installing and re-caching

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm registering my service worker, and in the registered callback, loading some cached files

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('swRoot.js').then(() => {
        console.log('registered');

        System.import('react');
        System.import('react-dom');
        System.import('a').then(({ a }) => console.log('value from a', a));
    }, err => console.log(err));
}
```

It works, but it seems closing the browser tab, and re-opening it is causing the install event to re-fire, which somehow results in a growing number of fetches / cache hits (see below) to log. Once the page is open, subsequent soft refreshes behave as expected; I only see cache hits for the few files I'm loading.

So the very first time the service worker is installed, I see 3 cache hits, for the 3 files I'm loading. If I close and re-open, I get 6, then 9, etc. In any case, simply refreshing the page shows the original 3 cache hits as expected.

**Why does closing and then re-opening the browser tab result in an increasing number of fetch events to fire for the same few files, but not on subsequent refreshes?**

The entirety of swRoot.js is below

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('INSTALLED');

    console.log('ADDING CACHE FILES');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/react-redux/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js',
                '/react-redux/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js',
                '/react-redux/a.js'
            ]).then(function(){ console.log('cache filling success'); }).catch(function(){ console.log('cache filling failure') });
        })
    );
});

console.log('ADDING FETCH at root level');
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
                // Cache hit - return response
                if (response) {
                    console.log('cache hit', event.request);
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('ACTIVATE');
});
```

Comment: I wonder if your use of a relative URLs for the path to the SW script is leading to multiple SW registrations, which in turns leads to extra requests. Can you try with an absolute URL, e.g. `'/path/to/swRoot.js'` instead of `'swRoot.js'`? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33881341/385997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the very first time the service worker is installed, I see 3 cache hits, for the 3 files I'm loading. If I close and re-open, I get 6, then 9, etc. In any case, simply refreshing the page shows the original 3 cache hits as expected.

Most probably is that you are seeing previous logs. To verify, you can show the timeline of every log.

1. Go to dev tools settings F1 inside console or click on the icon (img1)
2. Check the option Show timestamps (img2).
3. Or simple add a `console.log(new Date());` inside your fetch event handler.

### Img1

[image: dev tools settings]

### Img2

[image: show timestamps]

Now you will be able to identify logs that are from previous requests. Your **sw** is not making extra request, just the console is **keeping old logs**.

[image: showing time]

To fix it, do right click inside the console and click on **clear console history**.

Hope this help.

[image]

Comment: That's it - you nailed it. Thank you so much.  I can't (literally can't) award the bounty until tomorrow, but soon your rep will about double.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: As a bonus, do you happen to know how to have Chrome *never* cache these prior console logs?

Comment: No, I don't know. But I think this is more like a bug, this behavior is very confused.

Comment: Thanks anyway - and that notification reminded me to award the bounty :)

Comment: That's hilarious. Don't know how I actually lived without this console timestamp feature..

Answer (score 1):

It should not be there because the install event is called only once.I think the issue is in your chrome browser force update service worker is checked.Open developer console on chrome -> go to application tab -> service worker and uncheck **update on reload**.

Comment: Thanks for the response - sadly, that box is already unchecked.  Contrary to what I wrote originally, it looks like this happens only after closing my browser tab and re-opening it.  Refreshing within the page causes everything to behave as normal.

Comment: Can you check in your browser's console tab, is **preserve log** checkbox checked.I think it could be the issue.

Comment: Yep - that was it, as the other answer said.  Thanks again for the response!