# Understanding time stats in Chrome for Service Worker cached files

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to understand what the network tab in Chrome dev tools is telling me for cached files coming from Service Worker.

I'm seeing a cache hit get logged in the console (see the service worker code below), but the network tab is making it look like a regular network load.  230ms seems a bit big for a cache hit.  And the value usually changes by a small amount (next load might be, say, 217ms) so it's not showing me the original time to load, when it was first cached, as I wondered.

[image]

The code registering the service worker is this

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('swRoot.js').then(() => {
        console.log('registered');

        System.import('react');
        System.import('react-dom');
        System.import('a').then(({ a }) => console.log('value from a', a));
    }, err => console.log(err));
}
```

The entirety of `swRoot.js` is below

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('INSTALLED');

    console.log('ADDING CACHE FILES');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/react-redux/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js',
                '/react-redux/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js',
                '/react-redux/a.js'
            ]).then(function(){ console.log('cache filling success'); }).catch(function(){ console.log('cache filling failure') });
        })
    );
});

console.log('ADDING FETCH at root level');
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
                // Cache hit - return response
                if (response) {
                    console.log('cache hit', event.request);
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('ACTIVATE');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590378/status-code200-ok-from-serviceworker-in-chrome-network-devtools) has some background on how to interpret service worker involvement with entries in the Network panel.

The screenshot you provided shows a response returned from the service worker, without any network involvement, so it presumably came directly from the cache. (If there was another entry not included in your screenshot, with a little gear icon next to it, then that would be a different matter.)

The ~200ms timing displayed in the Network panel reflects the total amount of time that elapsed between the page making the request and the page obtaining the response. When a service worker is involved, both making a request and processing the response can be delayed if the page's main thread is performing other tasks. In your example, I assume the main thread is busy evaluating and executing a bunch of JavaScript as a result of your `System.import()` calls, so the ~200ms of overhead would likely be explained by that.

The Chromium team is evaluating ways of removing the main thread from the request/response critical path, and that's being tracked at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443374

Comment: Outstanding - thanks a ton.  Will look more closely here soon.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Ah - I see the duplicate entry with the gear icon indicating network involvement.  Making more sense!

Comment: If you're up for it, I have a fat bounty open on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081577/unchanged-service-worker-is-re-installing-and-re-caching