# Sharing fetch handler logic defined across multiple service workers

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-caching

Following [This Discussion](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/921#issuecomment-229956274), Where there is a comment that speaks of

#### patching a Fetch

> by overriding self.fetch, self.XMLHttpRequest, and self.caches (for 
>   cache.add/addAll)? It would seem these would let you intercept network  requests and manipulate responses before the main SW script sees them.

I have been looking out for any documentation that speaks of such stuff, and can not seem to find any.

In a scenario where I simply **need** `multiple` service workers to co exist in a single scope,

After having an `importScripts` in one of them to import the event handlers of the other,

How exactly would I patch a fetch / avoid a fetch race / have both the fetch handlers work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a few things to cover here:

**Multiple Service Workers in a Single Scope**

There can only be one active service worker for a given scope. If you attempt to register two different service worker scripts that each have the same scope, the second registration will trigger the [service worker update flow](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#updates):

```
// There's an implied default scope of '/'.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881341/385997
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw1.js');

// If called later on, this will trigger the update flow.
// You'll only end up with one of the two being active.
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw2.js');
```

The exact timing for when `sw2.js` will activate and take control over any existing clients depends on whether you're using `self.skipWaiting()` and `self.clients.claim()` inside of `sw2.js`. Once `sw2.js` activates, `sw1.js` will be marked as redundant.

Another way of asking what I think is the same question is whether you can have multiple service workers controlling the same client page at the same time. The answer is no, you can have at most one service worker controlling any client page, and only that service worker will be able to respond to `fetch` events originating from the page.

**Using importScripts to Share Common Handlers**

Instead of attempting to register multiple service workers with the same scope, using [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) to pull in logic that's defined in a different JavaScript file sounds like a reasonable approach. There are a few things to keep in mind when using `importScripts()` in this fashion:

- `importScripts()` needs to be called during the initial startup execution of your service worker code, not inside an event handler. I.e. "lazy-loading" of `importScripts()` is not supported.
- `importScripts()` executes all the of the code inside of the file(s) synchronously, one by one, in the order in which they're listed. You can have multiple `importScripts()`, or `importScripts()` inside of files that are themselves imported, and they'll all execute in a defined order.
- Inside an imported script, `self` will be set to the same [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) that would be used if the code were in the top-level service worker. I.e., there's no difference between calling `self.addEventListener()` inside of an imported script or inside of the top-level service worker.
- (This isn't directly related to your question, but it's good to know:) The files referenced via `importScripts()` will be cached by default, using the same mechanism that's built in to the browser for caching your top-level service worker file. While there are some changes to the service worker specification underway to change this, as of right now, those cached `importScripts()` files will be used indefinitely as long as their filenames don't change. So a best practice is to either include a version number or a hash in the file names of anything referenced with `importScripts()`.

**Multiple fetch Event Handlers**

What happens when you have multiple calls to `self.addEventListener('fetch')`?

From the previous section we know that it's not relevant whether those multiple calls originate inside of an `importScripts()` resource or the top-level service worker. They both operate on the same global scope.

The behavior is well-defined: when a client page makes a request, it will trigger the `fetch` handlers of the controlling service worker one by one, **in the order in which they were registered**, until the first call is made to `event.respondWith()`. One one `fetch` event handler calls `respondWith()`, no other fetch event handlers will be triggered, and it's the sole responsibility of that handler to (eventually) return a `Response` to the client page.

Since the order in which your `self.addEventlistener('fetch')` calls matter, make sure that you list the files in your `importScripts()` in an appropriate order, and either include your call to `importScripts()` before or after you define any `fetch` event handlers in your top-level service worker, depending on which you want to take precedence.

While you can use conditional logic to determine whether or not to call `event.respondWith()`, that logic can't be asynchronous, since the service worker won't wait to see whether `event.respondWith()` is called. It needs to synchronously move on to the next `event` handler (assuming there is one).

So inside a `fetch` handler, you can use conditional logic like

```
// This can be executed synchronously.
if (event.request.url.endsWith('.html')) {
  event.respondWith(...);
}
```

but you can't use conditional logic like:

```
// caches.match() is asynchronous, and the service worker will have
// moved on to the next `fetch` handler before it completes.
caches.match('index.html').then(response => {
  if (response) {
    event.respondWith(...);
  }
});
```

There's a [live code sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/multiple-handlers/index.html) that you can explore if you want to see the multiple-handlers behavior for yourself.

Comment: ServiceWorker files which were imported via `importScripts()` now have a better update mechanism from Chrome 78. See more details [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/fresher-sw/) in an article from Jeff himself.