# Should the Service Worker file be called on each individual page?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Should the service worker file be called from each page, through header.php for example, or just in one instance from the site index?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once a service worker is registered, it can take control of any page that's visited under its scope, and the browser will automatically [check for updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843970/service-worker-javascript-update-frequency-every-24-hours/38854905#38854905) whether or not there's another call made `navigator.serviceWorker.register()`.

So, it is *sufficient* to only call `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` on your main entry point, and not call it again on any other pages, if you're *sure* that all users will pass through that entry point at least once.

That being said, there's no harm in calling `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` multiple times. As long as the same URL is passed in each time, it will effectively "do nothing". I'd [recommend using an absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881341/385997), though, as relative URLs will be interpreted with the current page's URL as the base, which might lead to unexpected results if your web app uses URLs with paths that descend multiple levels. The advantage of calling `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` on each page is that you'll still end up with a service worker being registered even if your users navigate directly to a sub-page of your site, without visiting the main page first.